# failed to load language plugin ${language} in pulumi

Tags: ubuntu, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code, pulumi-python

I'm new to pulumi and trying to run a pulumi review but getting following error,

what I've tried so far,

I tried install following tools in my Ubuntu host :

```
python3

python3 -m venv venv
```

Then, tried follwing commnads in pulumi,

```
pulumi loing gs://<gcs_location>

pulumi stack select k8s

pulumi preview
```

error :

```
error: failed to load language plugin ${language}: no language plugin 'pulumi-language-${language}' found in the workspace or on your $PATH, install the plugin using `pulumi plugin install language ${language}`
```

update : pulumi.yaml

```
    name: ${pulumi_project_name}
runtime:
  name: ${language}
  options:
    virtualenv: ${lang_virutal_env}
description: Pulumi with Gitlab
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us your `Pulumi.yaml` file? (remove any sensitive info if any)

Comment: @MikhailShilkov added pulumi.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you copied your `Pulumi.yaml` from a template as-is? It should have no templated values in it, here is a valid example ([source](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/aws-py-s3-folder/Pulumi.yaml)):

```
name: aws-py-s3-folder
runtime:
  name: python
  options:
    virtualenv: venv
description: A minimal AWS Python Pulumi program
```